# $\int \sqrt{\sqrt{x}}\left ( x \frac{1}{x} \right )dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I think $\int \sqrt{x}\left ( x\frac{1}{x} \right )dx = \int x^{1/2}\left ( x + x^{-1} \right )dx$

What about $\int \sqrt{\sqrt{x}}\left ( x \frac{1}{x} \right )dx$ is $\int x^{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}}\left ( x + x^{-1} \right )dx$ ?

Is it true ?

Comment: But $x^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)} \left(x \frac{1}{x} \right) = x^{\frac{1}{4}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Notice, in case of product one should clearly write: $x\cdot \frac 1x$ or $x\times \frac 1x$ that equals to $1$
>
> But if $x$ & $\frac 1x$ are not having sign of product between them then
>
> it is true that $$x\frac 1x=\frac{x^2+1}{x}=x+\frac{1}{x}= x+x^{-1}$$ so one should have $$\sqrt{\sqrt x}\left(x\frac 1x\right)\ dx=\int x^{\frac 12\frac 12}\left(x+\frac 1x\right)\ dx=\int x^{1/4}\left(x+x^{-1}\right)\ dx$$